# free(): in valid pointer exception - While reading a huge file using streams

Tags: c++, algorithm, counting

**Edit:
So i noticed my article.txt file has characters which were not ASCII .So i changed the MAX_CHAR_COUNT to 256 and now I am getting segmentation fault error**

I am writing a C++ ( new to it )solution to find the occurrences of words in file words.txt in a huge file which cannot fit in memory with a suffix tree.

I am reading 4 lines at a time from stream (4 is just an example,  i will benchmark the number of lines later after profiling ).

When i run the programme with small file , it works fine .But when I run the programme with actual file , i am facing error :

```
.....    

building suffix tree 
    text is :       Template      Template talk      Help      Help talk      Category
    free end  -432 , 71 
    free node 
    free end  -1 , 71 
    *** Error in `./needleInHaystack': free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000606140 ***
    ======= Backtrace: =========
    /lib64/libc.so.6(+0x81679)[0x7ff83d338679]
    ./needleInHaystack[0x4017c9]
    ./needleInHaystack[0x401775]
    ./needleInHaystack[0x401775]
    ./needleInHaystack[0x401775]
    ./needleInHaystack[0x401775]
    ./needleInHaystack[0x401775]
    ./needleInHaystack[0x401775]
    ./needleInHaystack[0x401d88]
    /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7ff83d2d9505]
    ./needleInHaystack[0x4010d9]
    ======= Memory map: ========
    00400000-00406000 r-xp 00000000 00:51 16651445                           /usr/local/rms/needleInHaystack
    00605000-00606000 r--p 00005000 00:51 16651445                           /usr/local/rms/needleInHaystack
    00606000-00607000 rw-p 00006000 00:51 16651445                           /usr/local/rms/needleInHaystack
    01f6d000-01faf000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
    7ff838000000-7ff838021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7ff838021000-7ff83c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7ff83d2b7000-7ff83d47a000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3547654                    /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
    7ff83d47a000-7ff83d67a000 ---p 001c3000 08:01 3547654                    /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
    7ff83d67a000-7ff83d67e000 r--p 001c3000 08:01 3547654                    /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
    7ff83d67e000-7ff83d680000 rw-p 001c7000 08:01 3547654                    /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
    7ff83d680000-7ff83d685000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7ff83d685000-7ff83d69a000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3547686                    /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
    7ff83d69a000-7ff83d899000 ---p 00015000 08:01 3547686                    /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
    7ff83d899000-7ff83d89a000 r--p 00014000 08:01 3547686                    /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
    7ff83d89a000-7ff83d89b000 rw-p 00015000 08:01 3547686                    /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
    7ff83d89b000-7ff83d99c000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3547702                    /usr/lib64/libm-2.17.so
    7ff83d99c000-7ff83db9b000 ---p 00101000 08:01 3547702                    /usr/lib64/libm-2.17.so
    7ff83db9b000-7ff83db9c000 r--p 00100000 08:01 3547702                    /usr/lib64/libm-2.17.so
    7ff83db9c000-7ff83db9d000 rw-p 00101000 08:01 3547702                    /usr/lib64/libm-2.17.so
    7ff83db9d000-7ff83dc86000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3547770                    /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
    7ff83dc86000-7ff83de85000 ---p 000e9000 08:01 3547770                    /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
    7ff83de85000-7ff83de8d000 r--p 000e8000 08:01 3547770                    /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
    7ff83de8d000-7ff83de8f000 rw-p 000f0000 08:01 3547770                    /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
    7ff83de8f000-7ff83dea4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7ff83dea4000-7ff83dec6000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3547624                    /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so
    7ff83e0b7000-7ff83e0bc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7ff83e0c2000-7ff83e0c5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7ff83e0c5000-7ff83e0c6000 r--p 00021000 08:01 3547624                    /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so
    7ff83e0c6000-7ff83e0c7000 rw-p 00022000 08:01 3547624                    /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so
    7ff83e0c7000-7ff83e0c8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7ffdfed2f000-7ffdfed50000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
    7ffdfedc9000-7ffdfedcb000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
    7ffdfedcb000-7ffdfedcd000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
    ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
    Aborted
```

Following is my code and for now I am only trying the occurances of one word by hardcoding which is string : "make" :

```
#define MAX_CHAR 256 
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<cstring>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;


struct SuffixTreeNode { 
    struct SuffixTreeNode *children[MAX_CHAR]; 

    struct SuffixTreeNode *suffixLink; 
    int start; 
    int *end; 

    int suffixIndex; 
}; 

typedef struct SuffixTreeNode Node; 
string text;  


Node *root = NULL; //Pointer to root node 

Node *lastNewNode = NULL; 
Node *activeNode = NULL; 

int activeEdge = -1; 
int activeLength = 0; 

int remainingSuffixCount = 0; 
int leafEnd = -1; 
int *rootEnd = NULL; 
int *splitEnd = NULL; 
int size = -1; //Length of input string 

Node *newNode(int start, int *end) 
{ 
    Node *node =(Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node)); 
    int i; 
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_CHAR; i++) 
        node->children[i] = NULL; 


    node->suffixLink = root; 
    node->start = start; 
    node->end = end; 

    node->suffixIndex = -1; 
    return node; 
} 

int edgeLength(Node *n) { 
    if(n == root) 
        return 0; 
    return *(n->end) - (n->start) + 1; 
} 

int walkDown(Node *currNode) 
{ 

    if (activeLength >= edgeLength(currNode)) 
    { 
        activeEdge += edgeLength(currNode); 
        activeLength -= edgeLength(currNode); 
        activeNode = currNode; 
        return 1; 
    } 
    return 0; 
} 

void extendSuffixTree(int pos)
{

leafEnd = pos;

remainingSuffixCount++;

lastNewNode = NULL;

while(remainingSuffixCount > 0) {

if (activeLength == 0)
activeEdge = pos; 


if (activeNode->children[text[activeEdge]] == NULL)
{
activeNode->children[text[activeEdge]] =
newNode(pos, &leafEnd);


if (lastNewNode != NULL)
{
lastNewNode->suffixLink = activeNode;
lastNewNode = NULL;
}
}

else
{

Node *next = activeNode->children[text[activeEdge]];
if (walkDown(next)){
continue;
}

if (text[next->start + activeLength] == text[pos])
{

if(lastNewNode != NULL && activeNode != root)
{
lastNewNode->suffixLink = activeNode;
lastNewNode = NULL;
}

activeLength++;

break;
}

splitEnd = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
*splitEnd = next->start + activeLength - 1;

Node *split = newNode(next->start, splitEnd);
activeNode->children[text[activeEdge]] = split;

split->children[text[pos]] = newNode(pos, &leafEnd);
next->start += activeLength;
split->children[text[next->start]] = next;


if (lastNewNode != NULL)
{

lastNewNode->suffixLink = split;
}

lastNewNode = split;
}


remainingSuffixCount--;
if (activeNode == root && activeLength > 0) 
{
activeLength--;
activeEdge = pos - remainingSuffixCount + 1;
}
else if (activeNode != root) 
{
activeNode = activeNode->suffixLink;
}
}
}
void print(int i, int j) 
{ 
    int k; 
    for (k=i; k<=j; k++) 
        printf("%c", text[k]); 
} 

void setSuffixIndexByDFS(Node *n, int labelHeight) 
{ 
    if (n == NULL) return; 
    int leaf = 1; 
    int i; 
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_CHAR; i++) 
    { 
        if (n->children[i] != NULL) 
        { 

            leaf = 0; 
            setSuffixIndexByDFS(n->children[i], labelHeight + 
                                edgeLength(n->children[i])); 
        } 
    } 
    if (leaf == 1) 
    { 
        n->suffixIndex = size - labelHeight; 

    } 
} 

void freeSuffixTreeByPostOrder(Node *n) 
{ 
    if (n == NULL) 
        return; 
    int i; 
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_CHAR; i++) 
    { 
        if (n->children[i] != NULL) 
        { 
            freeSuffixTreeByPostOrder(n->children[i]); 
        } 
    } 

    printf("free end  %d , %d \n", n->suffixIndex, *(n->end));
    if (n->suffixIndex == -1) 
        free(n->end); 

    printf("free node \n");
    free(n); 
} 


void buildSuffixTree() 
{ 
    printf("building suffix tree \n");
    size = text.length(); 
    int i; 
    rootEnd = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)); 
    *rootEnd = - 1; 


    root = newNode(-1, rootEnd); 

    activeNode = root; 
    for (i=0; i<size; i++) 
        extendSuffixTree(i); 
    int labelHeight = 0; 
    setSuffixIndexByDFS(root, labelHeight); 
} 

int traverseEdge(const char *str, int idx, int start, int end) 
{ 
    int k = 0; 
    for(k=start; k<=end && str[idx] != '\0'; k++, idx++) 
    { 
        if(text[k] != str[idx]) 
            return -1; // mo match 
    } 
    if(str[idx] == '\0') 
        return 1; // match 
    return 0; // more characters yet to match 
} 

int doTraversalToCountLeaf(Node *n) 
{ 
    if(n == NULL) 
        return 0; 
    if(n->suffixIndex > -1) 
    { 
        return 1; 
    } 
    int count = 0; 
    int i = 0; 
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_CHAR; i++) 
    { 
        if(n->children[i] != NULL) 
        { 
            count += doTraversalToCountLeaf(n->children[i]); 
        } 
    } 
    return count; 
} 

int countLeaf(Node *n) 
{ 
    if(n == NULL) 
        return 0; 
    return doTraversalToCountLeaf(n); 
} 

// returns count in the current buffer 
int doTraversal(Node *n,const char* str, int idx) 
{ 
    if(n == NULL) 
    { 
        return -1; // no match 
    } 
    int res = -1; 
    if(n->start != -1) 
    { 
        res = traverseEdge(str, idx, n->start, *(n->end)); 
        if(res == -1) //no match 
            return -1; 
        if(res == 1) //match 
        { 
            if(n->suffixIndex > -1) 
                return 1;
            else
                return countLeaf(n); 

        } 
    } 
    idx = idx + edgeLength(n); 

    if(n->children[str[idx]] != NULL) 
        return doTraversal(n->children[str[idx]], str, idx); 
    else
        return -1; // no match 
} 

int checkForSubString(const char* str) 
{ 
    int res = doTraversal(root, str, 0); 
    if(res != 1) 
        return 0;
    return res;
} 



int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{ 


    unordered_map<string, int> map;

    // read file 
    ifstream words;
    string allLines[1000];

        words.open("words.txt");
    int i =0;
        for (string line; getline(words, line);)
    {
            allLines[i] = line;
        map[line] = 0;

    }

    allLines[0] = "make";
    map[allLines[0]] = 0;

    ifstream article;
    string artlines;
        article.open ("article.txt");
    i=0;
    for (string line; getline(article, line);)
    {
        if(line.length() == 0 ){
            continue;
        }

        if(i == 4){
            i=0;
            text = artlines;
            buildSuffixTree();
            printf("text is : %s\n" , text.c_str() );
            map[allLines[0]]+= checkForSubString(allLines[0].c_str());
            artlines = line;
            freeSuffixTreeByPostOrder(root); 
        }else{
            printf("counter I is %d\n",i);
            artlines += line;
            ++i;
        }
    }

    printf("out of loop \n");

    if(i != 4 && i != 0){
        text = artlines;
        //buildSuffixTree();
        //map[allLines[0]]+= checkForSubString(allLines[0].c_str());
        freeSuffixTreeByPostOrder(root); 
    }

    printf("make count : %d",map[allLines[0]]);

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: See [the book guide here on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: @uneven_mark , i can understand it . Right now my focus is on making this code run . I will try to see how is mixing c style related to the error i am facing .

Comment: The code is way too long to go through and fix all errors. It being confusingly written does not help.

Comment: i will migrate it to c++ , thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 4):

In some cases you call `newNode(pos, &leafEnd);` where `&leafEnd` is not an address returned from `malloc`.

In other cases you have e.g.

```
splitEnd = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
*splitEnd = some_value;
Node *split = newNode(next->start, splitEnd);
```

You have to always dynamically allocate the memory you pass to `newNode` because you later use `free(n->end);`. This is not allowed if `n->end` is the address of a local or global variable instead of an address returned from a previous `malloc`.

Example:

Instead of

```
split->children[text[pos]] = newNode(pos, &leafEnd);
```

you can use something like

```
int *copyOfLeafEnd = malloc(sizeof(int));
/* check for NULL and do error handling */
*copyOfLeafEnd = leafEnd;
split->children[text[pos]] = newNode(pos, copyOfLeafEnd);
```

Comment: how is this related to free() and how can i dynamically allocate memory ? I am new to C++ but I only have the design approach which I was trying to translate using c++

Comment: @DivyanshuJimmy Dynamic allocation is what you are doing with `malloc`. You are not allowed to call `free` on any pointer not returned by a call to `malloc`. Since `leafEnd` is a global variable, `&leafEnd` is a pointer not returned by `malloc` and you are potentially calling `free` on it.

Comment: @uneven_mark , i have updated my question with Edit on top . I think this part is fixed but still I am getting segmentation fault

Comment: let me test this after my dinner and and i will get back to you .thanks  bodo and @uneven_mark

Comment: @DivyanshuJimmy Segmentation fault and invalid `free` are both manifestations of [*undefined behavior*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior) which happens if you violate the rules of C++. You do not seem to know what these rules are. C++ requires you to follow these rules and if you don't it will not warn you about it. Instead your program will do anything or nothing.

Comment: i got it @uneven_mark , i will move code snippet from c  to c++ as i can see warning with WAll

Comment: @DivyanshuJimmy What I wrote applies equally to C. Also in both C and C++ you *need* to go through all warnings the compiler gives you and evaluate each one. Most of the time they are indicative of one such rule violation I mentioned above.

Comment: @DivyanshuJimmy You won't get warnings about invalid `free` from the compiler, even with `-Wall` or other warning options. If you run your program in a debugger and get a run-time error, you can see at which place you get the error. Better use a memory checker like `valgrind`.